# Face structures of chain polytopes

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, order-theory, posets

For a finite poset $P$ the chain polytope $\mathscr C(P)\subset\mathbb{R}^P$ consists of such $g$ that $g(p)\ge 0$ for all $p\in P$ and $$g(p_1)+\ldots+g(p_n)\le 1$$ for any chain $p_1<\ldots<p_n$.

In [this paper](http://dedekind.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/66.pdf) R. Stanley does not provide an explicit description of the face structure of $\mathscr C(P)$ due to it "seeming messy".

My question is: has, by any chance, a less messy approach been discovered since then?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01706